# nestjs e2e testing graphql using supertest response error 404

Tags: api, graphql, nestjs, e2e-testing, prisma2

when i run e2e test :

and this is

**app.Module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      cors: {
        origin: process.env.FRONTENDURL,
        credentials: true,
      },
      installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
      autoSchemaFile: 'src/schema.gql',
      context: ({ req, res, url }) => ({
        headers: req.headers,
        res,
        url: req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host,
      }),
    }),
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    UserModule,
    BusinessModule,
    PrismaModule,
    ReviewModule,
    LikeModule,
    FollowModule,
    ImageModule,
    LocationModule,
    CategoryModule,
    ReportModule,
    ClaimModule,
    FeedModule,
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [ClaimResolver, ClaimService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and
**main.ts**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
    cors: true,
  });
  app.use(cookieParser('Secret'));
  app.enableCors({
    origin: process.env.FRONTENDURL,
    credentials: true,
  });
  //app.setViewEngine('hbs');
  await app.listen(5000);
}
bootstrap();
```

so here is my

**app.e2e-spec.ts**

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { ExecutionContext, INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { AppModule } from './../src/app.module';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthGuard } from '../src/utils/auth/auth.guard';

const gql = '/graphql';

describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

it('loged in', async () => {
    const result = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post(gql)
      .send({
        query: `mutation login{
        login(data:{
          email:"alaa@gmail.com",
          password: "alaa01151116980",
        }){
          token
          user{
            userName
            id
          }
        }
      }`,
      })
      // .expect(404)
      .expect((response) => {
        expect(response.body.data.login.token).toEqual(
          expect.objectContaining({
            login: {
              token: expect.any(String),
            },
          }),
        );
      });
  });
});
```

and i got the error

```
● AppController (e2e) › loged in

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined

      108 |       // .expect(404)
      109 |       .expect((response) => {
    > 110 |         expect(response.body.data.login.token).toEqual(
          |                                   ^
      111 |           expect.objectContaining({
      112 |             login: {
      113 |               token: expect.any(String),

      at app.e2e-spec.ts:110:35
      at ../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:80:15
      at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test._assertFunction (../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:311:11)
      at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test.assert (../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:201:21)
      at Server.localAssert (../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:159:12)

A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        30.379 s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press o to only run tests related to changed files.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

when i change the response in **app.e2e-spec.ts** file to:

```
it('loged in', async () => {
    const result = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post(gql)
      .send({
        query: `mutation login{
        login(data:{
          email:"alaa@gmail.com",
          password: "alaa01151116980",
        }){
          token
          user{
            userName
            id
          }
        }
      }`,
      })
      // .expect(404)
      .expect((response) => {
        expect(response).toEqual(
          expect.objectContaining({
            login: {
              token: expect.any(String),
            },
          }),
        );
      });
  });
```

i have the recived response

```
● AppController (e2e) › loged in

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: ObjectContaining {"login": {"token": Any<String>}}
    Received: {"header": {"connection": "close", "content-length": "147", "content-security-policy": "default-src 'none'", "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "date": "Fri, 07 May 2021 03:30:24 GMT", "x-content-type-options": "nosniff", "x-powered-by": "Express"}, "req": {"data": {"query": "mutation login{ 
            login(data:{
              email:\"alaa@gmail.com\",
              password: \"alaa01151116980\",
            }){
              token
              user{
                userName
                id
              }
            }
          }"}, "headers": {"content-type": "application/json"}, "method": "POST", "url": "http://127.0.0.1:55679/graphql"}, "status": 404, "text": "<!DOCTYPE 
html>
    <html lang=\"en\">
    <head>
    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
    <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <pre>Cannot POST /graphql</pre>
    </body>
    </html>
    "}

      108 |       // .expect(404)
      109 |       .expect((response) => {
    > 110 |         expect(response).toEqual(
          |                          ^
      111 |           expect.objectContaining({
      112 |             login: {
      113 |               token: expect.any(String),

      at app.e2e-spec.ts:110:26
      at ../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:80:15
      at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test._assertFunction (../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:311:11)
      at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test.assert (../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:201:21)
      at Server.localAssert (../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:159:12)

A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        20.85 s, estimated 29 s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

i notice something here i got 404 status code not found and a different url port not match the backend url i used , so i thing the supertest request to the wrong url and recived {data : "null"} but i didn't know how to fix it .